# Is is normal for Windows 8 Build 9200 to report "You're using a prerelease version of Windows 8"

Tags: windows-8

When you encounter a compatibility warning, you're redirected to a help topic for more information.

On my Windows 8 Pro x64 RTM, downloaded from MSDN and installed as an in-place upgrade on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, the compatibility help shows

> You're using a prerelease version of Windows 8.

when you expand the "What version of Windows as I using?" link.

[image]

Is this normal and expected behavior (something that Microsoft neglected to update during the release cycle) or is there something wrong with my install?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Strange but true, maybe because it is a MSDN release before it goes public? or MS screwed up.

Comment: @Moab: It'll be fun to have someone check one of the paid editions coming out later this month.

Comment: This seems to more of a problem with the fact, Windows 8 has not been released yet, I would wait until Oct 26 to change anything about your system.

Comment: @Ramhound: Windows 8 has already been released to MSDN subscribers.  But perhaps it's pulling information from a web server somewhere that isn't ready for the release (if true, that would totally destroy the value of the information shown, because it doesn't reflect the local system).

Answer (score 0):

When you download Windows 8 from MSDN, it's indeed the build `9200.16420`, but the official one might be `9200.16500` or something like that... Microsoft is hard to understand with there "build" in Windows.

I have exactly the same release and I have the same problem. Even if I got it from MSDNAA!

When the official will be released, just upgrade from the pre-release to the official one or keep the RC until it desactivate.

Comment: Your solution to his problem is to use Release Preview which means no upgrade path ( only able to transfer user files ) and what is clearly an unsupported version of Windows 8?